# Find $P(\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i>50)$ if $X_i\sim U\{\pm 1,\dots,\pm 6\}$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, generating-functions, simulation

A stock is currently worth \$$100$. each day a coin is flipped and a dice rolled. If the coin lands heads the stock price increases by the rolled value of the dice in $. If the coin lands tails, the stock price decreases by rolled value of the dice. What is probability that after 10 days the stock is worth more than 150?

What I've tried is that 50 is such a large number that if you don't roll a 6, you have to roll 5*5 for the dice every day. And then to discuss case by case of rolling one 6,two 6 and so on.But that's a lot of work and seems tedious for 10 cases.

Anyone can give me some insights on this?

Comment: I think breaking it down into cases is the right approach, but, as you point out, you can fail to roll a lot of 6s and still reach 150. What you can't do is flip a lot of tails and still reach 150, so try breaking it into cases based on the coin flips.

Comment: Thanks.I've combined the coin flip and dice roll results so every time the number should go up 6,5,4,3,2,1,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6and I explore the situation with no "6",one "6",2"6",but I just find the latter cases are hard to discuss since I should do until 10 "6".So I just don't know what to do.

Comment: I estimate this at around $3\times 10^{-6}$ by some rough intuition, since even with $10$ heads, the requirement is $3$ standard deviations out.

Comment: @BenjaminWang, you may be right. After programming more precisely I get probability in $[0,4\times 10^{-6})$ range. But, this should be tough to calculate this by calculations.

Comment: @OM it shouldn't be too hard to enumerate the all-heads case. After all, there's a simple algorithm to calculate probabilities for multiple dice: `[1,1,1]-> [[0,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1]] -> sum to give [0,1,2,3,2,1]` as an example of 2 3-sided dice.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I calculated the probability exactly, and found that it was $\approx 1.4564\times 10^{-6}$. So, good estimate!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can exactly solve this using the methodology of probability generating functions, together with a computer to help us crunch the numbers.

Let $f(x)$ be the probability generating function for the price increase of a single day. This increase is equally likely to be any number in $\{-6,-5,\dots,-1,1,2,\dots,6\}$, so
$$
f(x)=
\tfrac1{12}x^{-6}+\tfrac1{12}x^{-5}+\dots+\tfrac1{12}x^{-1}+
\tfrac1{12}x^{1}+\tfrac1{12}x^{2}+\dots+\tfrac1{12}x^{6}
$$
I have not defined what a probability generating function is, but hopefully the above makes it somewhat clear. The probability generating function (pgf) encodes a probability distribution, with the coefficient of $x^n$ giving the probability of the value $n$.

It follows that the probability generating for the sum of the increases over ten days is $(f(x))^{10}$. This is the magic of probability generating functions; adding independent random variables corresponds to multiplication of pgf's. Therefore, we just need to compute $(f(x))^{10}$, and add up the coefficients of $x^n$, as $n$ ranges from $51$ to $60$. You can either do this with a computer-algebra-system, or you can directly write a program which multiplies pgf's, via the lists of their coefficients. I did the latter, and I found that the probability of the price increasing by more than $50$ over ten days is $$\frac{90\,178}{12^{10}}=\frac{45\,089}{30\,958\,682\,112}\approx 1.4564\times 10^{-6}.$$

Here is the Python program I used to compute this answer:

```
from fractions import Fraction    
    
def poly_multiply(P, Q):    
    """    
    P and Q are lists of numbers.     
    P represents a polynomial, where the coefficient    
    of x^k in P is P[k]. Same for Q.    
    Returns a list, representing the polynomial product P * Q.    
    """    
    
    # Initialize a list long enough to store largest coefficient of P * Q.    
    ret = [0] * (len(P) + len(Q) - 1)     
    # The coefficient of x^k in P * Q is the sum of    
    # P[i] * Q[j] over all i,j for which i + j = k.      
    for i in range(len(P)):    
        for j in range(len(Q)):    
            ret[i + j] += P[i] * Q[j]    
    return ret    
    
def poly_power(P, n):    
    ret = [1] # Initially, ret is the constant polynomial 1.    
    for _ in range(n):    
        ret = poly_multiply(P, ret) # Repeatedly multiply by P.    
    return ret     

# Initialize the pgf for the random gain over one day. 
# Instead of using the exact PGF, which has powers of x from -6 to 6,    
# we will instead multiply this by x^6, giviing a polynomial with degree 12.     
# This introduces an offset of 6 between the indices and coefficients.    
# That is, one_day_pgf[k] is the probabily that the gain is k - 6.    
one_day_pgf = [Fraction(1,12)] * 6 + [0] + [Fraction(1,12)] * 6    
    
# The ten-day gain is the tenth power of the one-day gain.    
# The offset from before is multiplied, so ten_day_pgf[k]    
# is the probability that the ten-day gain is k - 60.    
ten_day_pgf = poly_power(one_day_pgf, 10)    
    
# Find the probability that the gain is above 50.    
# The +60 in the index accounts for the offset. 
P_above_50 = sum(ten_day_pgf[gain + 60] for gain in range(51, 61))    
    
print('Exact probability:', P_above_50)    
print('Approximate probability:', float(P_above_50))
```

Comment: Thanks. Wow, I just realised generating functions method is the same as [discrete convolution method for positive dice (see bottom of answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60587959/11524527). By the way, it might be worth un-simplifying the answer to keep $12^{10}$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

I have programmed the code, after $100000$ simulations I found that probability is $0.0000$; Moreover, I found that if dice always show $6$ even then probability to get more than $150$ is $0.0010$.

```
import random

def simulate_stock_price(days, current_price):
    if days == 0:
        return current_price > 150

    coin_flip = random.choice(['Heads', 'Tails'])
    dice_roll = random.randint(1, 6)
    
    if coin_flip == 'Heads':
        current_price += dice_roll
    else:
        current_price -= dice_roll

    return simulate_stock_price(days - 1, current_price)

def calculate_probability(num_simulations, days):
    num_successful_simulations = 0
    for _ in range(num_simulations):
        if simulate_stock_price(days, 100):
            num_successful_simulations += 1

    return num_successful_simulations / num_simulations

num_simulations = 100000
days = 10

probability = calculate_probability(num_simulations, days)
print(f"Estimated probability after {days} days: {probability:.4f}")
```

Comment: Maybe some more simulation repeats or advanced importance sampling is required to get an accurate result (see my comment on the question).

Comment: @Lili I think you accepted this too quickly

Comment: Yeah@BenjaminWang. Anyway, still thanks to this computational way of simulating the problem.

Comment: @Lili, Thanks. But, that answer is more powerful computer programing than mine. Because to add up the coefficients of $x^n$ you need powerful computer-algebra-system which itself a lot of programming.

Comment: @OM I don't think my answer requires any especially sophisticated programming. I edited my answer to add my code; if you delete my comments, my code is shorter than yours!

Comment: @MikeEarnest Good. But when I put in `P_above_50 = sum(ten_day_pgf[gain + 60] for gain in range(-100, -65))` in your code. I get shocking probablility 0.048192287549659374 which is impossible because for all tail case it should be -60